# How to execute one python file with the arguments from another python file without passing arguments on command/terminal line?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a default code in Python that has the argument parser and have to pass those argument by myself in command line,but i dont want to pass the arguments myself rather execute that file from another python file with the arguments written in that file or i dont want to write those arguments myself on command lines.

My argument parsing code is as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument('-i', type=str, nargs='+', help="Enter the filenames with extention of an Image")
     arg=parser.parse_args()

    if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
    parser.print_help()
    exit()
```

my function is

```
def Predict_Emotion(filename):
      print "Opening image...."
      try:
          img=io.imread(filename)
          cvimg=cv2.imread(filename)
     except:
           print "Exception: File Not found."
           return
```

And my execution line is as

```
for filename in arg.i:
     Predict_Emotion(filename)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very unclear. If you want to pass arguments to a function, what's stopping you from just doing it?

Comment: Beginner at that.can you please explain!! @DanielRoseman

Comment: I can't, no, because as I said I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: in the above programme i have to pass arguments as myfile.py -i something.jpg , but i want to include this argument in the code itself so i dont have to type all arguments myself in command line. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Is that you want to test your argparse functionality programmatically or by-pass argparge all together?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack i dont want to execute the python script writing the arguments on command rather i want those arguments to pass from the function or programme itself.

Comment: So just remove the argparse part and hard code the values

Comment: i am having error while hard coding and having error while passing those arguments through function. Comment below executes  but dosen't give any result. @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: `Predict_Emothion` takes a string. `arg.i` returns a list of strings. Try replacing `arg.i` with a list of strings

Comment: can you email me with the example or how to do it, or you can post it right here!! @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: Lists and string are Python basics. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: can you take alook at my whole code and figure out how to do it, @AlastairMcCormack

Comment: SO is not a code generation/home work completion site. Please take the time to learn the basics and come back here when you have a specific problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it. You need to slightly modify the above code to form the following

```
import sys, argparse

def run_function (lista):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', type=str, nargs='+', help="Enter the filenames with extention of an Image")
    arg=parser.parse_args(lista)
    if (len(sys.argv) <= 1):
        parser.print_help()
        exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_function (sys.argv)
```

Reference used: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

That will now allow you to give it your own list from another file. To call it from the other file, you need to do the following

```
#These below two lines are not necessary if stating python in directory the script is in, or if it is already in your Python Path
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path to directory script is in")
#Below lines are now necessary
import your_script #NOTE this is the name of your file without the .py extention on the end
list_of_files = ["file1", "file2"]
your_script.run_function(list_of_files)
```

I think that is everything you asked!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and get back to you

Comment: N. i have some error regarding this still. can  you explain ho to properly implement.

Comment: Sorry - my fault entirely. There was a typo in the above code - instead of if (len(sys.argv) =< 1): it should read if (len(sys.argv) <= 1): - notice which way round the = and the < sign is. Apologies for that...

Comment: it says 'module' object has no attribute 'run_function" in my calling python file.

Comment: still says unrecognized arguments in my parser file. i have added my picture name "happy.jpg" to the list of files. Any solutions??@

Comment: I cannot say for certain what the problem is. You should run your_script.py happy.jpg -argparse_options to run it normally. If calling from another file, for each file, you need to run your_script.run_function( ["happy.jpg", -argparse_options] ) separately. You cannot run multiple files for that function. If you have a list of files (called list_files), then say ########

for item_file in list_of_files:
  your_script.run_function( [item_file, -argparse_options] )

########## Do it with appropriate new lines. Let me know if this is not the problem